# Ruby Type Class Missmatch Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nameerror, type-mismatch

Platform: Ubuntu 12.10

In my terminal, I am trying to run `bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb`

I am following the Learn Web Development: the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl to test a user.

My code is the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base      
    attr_accessible :email, :name  
end
```

My error is shown below:

```
root@NIyi-PC:/usr/sample_app# bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb 
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
/usr/sample_app/app/models/user.rb:13:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class User (TypeError)
```

Comment: This is occurring not because of namesapce issues, but because you already have a `User` class and you're trying to define another one. Do you define a class named `User` anywhere else in your code? Can you show us your `user_spec.rb`, since I bet that might be the culprit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error will happen if you've already declared `class User` elsewhere first in your code:

```
1.9.3-p374 :001 > class Bar; end
 => nil
1.9.3-p374 :002 > class Foo; end # first declaration, no superclass
 => nil
1.9.3-p374 :003 > class Foo < Bar; end # attempting to declare superclass later
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Foo
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/Mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

vs.

```
1.9.3-p374 :001 > class Bar; end
 => nil
1.9.3-p374 :002 > class Foo < Bar; end # first declaration, including superclass
 => nil
1.9.3-p374 :003 > class Foo; end # don't have to mention the superclass later
 => nil
```

This can be difficult to track down sometimes, but an easy starting point would be to search your entire project for "class User".

Comment: Sorry I was just in class. But I see the difference that you have in your 2 codes.

Comment: Sorry I was just in class. But I see the difference that you have in your 2 codes.                                                            @Veraticus                                                                **# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key  
#  name       :string(255)  
#  email      :string(255)  
#  created_at :datetime         not null  
#  updated_at :datetime         not null  
#

require 'spec_helper'  

describe User do    
      pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end**

Comment: I found out the problem. I had an old example_user.rb file where I declared the User class a couple weeks ago. I forgot all about it but when I discovered it, I deleted it. Thanks a lot for all of your help!